# Desactualización de paquetes al actualizar anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows10, anaconda, conda

Al intentar actualizar[anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda) en **Windows 10** por la consola como  usuario root me dice que necesita desactualizar paquetes, cosa que no quiero.

Esta es la salida por terminal:

```
F:\MISCOSAS\LIBRO RAICES CON PROGRAMAS\LibroRaices>conda update anaconda
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Anaconda3:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    cloudpickle-0.1.1          |           py35_0          16 KB
    dill-0.2.4                 |           py35_0          37 KB
    heapdict-1.0.0             |           py35_0           2 KB
    locket-0.2.0               |           py35_0           2 KB
    mkl-service-1.1.2          |           py35_0           9 KB
    qtpy-1.0                   |           py35_0          17 KB
    chest-0.2.3                |           py35_0           5 KB
    gevent-1.1.0               |           py35_0         442 KB
    qtawesome-0.3.2            |           py35_0         153 KB
    singledispatch-3.4.0.3     |           py35_0          13 KB
    conda-manager-0.3.1        |           py35_0         178 KB
    flask-cors-2.1.2           |           py35_0          16 KB
    partd-0.3.2                |           py35_1          25 KB
    anaconda-navigator-1.1.0   |           py35_0         1.2 MB
    dask-0.8.1                 |           py35_0         296 KB
    blaze-0.9.1                |           py35_0         580 KB
    anaconda-4.0.0             |      np110py35_0          16 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         3.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    anaconda-navigator: 1.1.0-py35_0
    blaze:              0.9.1-py35_0
    chest:              0.2.3-py35_0
    cloudpickle:        0.1.1-py35_0
    conda-manager:      0.3.1-py35_0
    dask:               0.8.1-py35_0
    dill:               0.2.4-py35_0
    flask-cors:         2.1.2-py35_0
    gevent:             1.1.0-py35_0
    heapdict:           1.0.0-py35_0
    locket:             0.2.0-py35_0
    mkl-service:        1.1.2-py35_0
    partd:              0.3.2-py35_1
    qtawesome:          0.3.2-py35_0
    qtpy:               1.0-py35_0
    singledispatch:     3.4.0.3-py35_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda:           2.4.1-np110py35_0  --> 4.0.0-np110py35_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    babel:              2.3.3-py35_0       --> 2.2.0-py35_0
    clyent:             1.2.2-py35_0       --> 1.2.1-py35_0
    cryptography:       1.3.1-py35_0       --> 1.3-py35_0
    cython:             0.24-py35_0        --> 0.23.4-py35_0
    h5py:               2.6.0-np110py35_1  --> 2.5.0-np110py35_4
    idna:               2.1-py35_0         --> 2.0-py35_0
    llvmlite:           0.10.0-py35_0      --> 0.9.0-py35_0
    nbconvert:          4.2.0-py35_0       --> 4.1.0-py35_0
    nltk:               3.2.1-py35_0       --> 3.2-py35_0
    numba:              0.25.0-np110py35_0 --> 0.24.0-np110py35_0
    numexpr:            2.5.2-np110py35_0  --> 2.5-np110py35_0
    path.py:            8.2-py35_0         --> 8.1.2-py35_1
    patsy:              0.4.1-py35_0       --> 0.4.0-np110py35_0
    pillow:             3.2.0-py35_0       --> 3.1.1-py35_0
    pygments:           2.1.3-py35_0       --> 2.1.1-py35_0
    pytest:             2.9.1-py35_0       --> 2.8.5-py35_0
    python-dateutil:    2.5.2-py35_0       --> 2.5.1-py35_0
    pytz:               2016.3-py35_0      --> 2016.2-py35_0
    qtconsole:          4.2.1-py35_0       --> 4.2.0-py35_1
    scipy:              0.17.0-np110py35_1 --> 0.17.0-np110py35_0
    setuptools:         20.7.0-py35_0      --> 20.3-py35_0
    sphinx:             1.4.1-py35_0       --> 1.3.5-py35_0
    werkzeug:           0.11.8-py35_0      --> 0.11.4-py35_0
    xlwings:            0.7.1-py35_0       --> 0.7.0-py35_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Además, me quiere instalar un paquete MKL, que si no recuerdo mal es de la edición de pago.

Comment: Es crucial tener la última versión de conda (> 4.0) porque han resuelto muchas cosas del cálculo de dependencias. https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.0.x/CHANGELOG.txt#L46-L62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al indicar a `conda` que actualice el metapaquete `anaconda` va a intenta ajustar tu entorno con las versiones de paquetes que se consideran estables y probados para trabajar con *Anaconda*.

Pero si no es éso lo que quieres, tal vez porque ya habías actualizado a mano algunos paquetes comunes, entonces lo que realmente quieres ejecutar es `conda update --all` para que actualice todos los paquetes posibles (aunque también puede desactualizar algún paquete si considera que es por el bien de la mayoría).

En cuanto a `MKL`, ya se incluye como parte de la versión libre de anaconda. Si te da algún aviso, en la documentación te cuentan cómo desactivarlo.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por qué hace una desactualización para actualizar anaconda de la 2.4.1 a la 4.0.0. He instalado todos los paquetes nuevos, he vuelto a querer actualizar anaconda y sigue igual.

Comment: No sé decirte si tiene algo qué ver windows10, porque en linux no me intenta desactualizar paquetes cuando intento actualizar de nuevo `anaconda`. Asegúrate de que tienes actualizado conda: `conda update conda`

Comment: @Tobal si has hecho `conda update --all` anteriormente y tienes versiones más modernas que las que vienen con `anaconda` ahí está la explicación.

Comment: @astrojuanlu Entonces si actualizo anaconda y luego hago un update --all, volveré a tener actualizados los paquetes que me desactualiza?

Comment: @Tobal Así es. También puedes hacer otra cosa mejor: créate un entorno virtual configurado con los paquetes que uses. De este modo, al actualizar anaconda no te *desactualizará* nada de tu entorno de trabajo, que podrás actualizar cuando quieras. Es muy fácil crear entornos con conda; pero si prefieres algo más visual y fácil ahí tienes [anaconda-navigator](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/navigator)

Comment: Exacto @Tobal. `conda update --all` te actualizará todo a la última versión. Considera `anaconda` como un metapaquete con unas versiones concretas probadas por Continuum, que pasados unos días no tienen por qué ser las más recientes.